# Spark : Use map and reduce with SparkSql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-dataset

I shouldnot be asking this question and I really don't want to ask, but I am lost. I see lots of tutorials that uses wordcount as example. But I am having problem to understand how to use it with sparkSql
for example, I have following query

```
Dataset<Row> totalItem = spark.sql(" select icode from bigmart.o_sales");
```

It gives me Dataset? now I can iterate over totalItem and print result but I want to count how many times the item occurs. This can be done with map and reduce , but I don't know how to do.
Also, if anyone knows sparkSql using java where we can store result in variable rather than using `show()`, I would be really gratefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count how many times a item occur you can do it using sparksql query itself  as follows:

`spark.sql("select icode,count(icode) from bigmart.o_sales group by icode")`

or you can use api as follows:

```
val df=spark.table("bigmart.o_sales").groupBy($"icode").count.show
```

Hope it answers your questions

Comment: thanks, I was writing the long way. but I still have some questions

Comment: Its old way of writing and may not be optimize but if you are doing something that is not possible with sql or dsl than you can use the map and reduce  .If you use sql then optimize plan is generated to avoid unnecessary computation

Comment: so, doing this 
`JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts =totalItem.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2<>(x.toString(), 1)).reduceByKey((x, y) -> x + y);System.out.println(counts.collect().get(8));`
is bad ?

Comment: As I said doing above is not bad but might not be fast as you might keep on serializing and de-serializing and type casting a lot while most of operation can be optimize which is taken care by spark sql

Comment: thanks, I chose your answer.It solved for me. Do you know any link where I can learn Spark sql with java because most of the tutorial is just copy paste of wordcount problem.

Comment: Apache documentation is quite good and sufficient to start with here is the link:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

it as both scala and java api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149470/discussion-between-sachin-janani-and-saurab).